# Android custom listview View with timer

Tags: android, listview, timer

I have a problem with the list. My list consists of two rows. The first is simply information about the object. When I click on the first item is presented a second row. It has a timer, everything works as expected, but the re-acquired by the time starts ticking faster. I understand that it is necessary to clean the list or am I just doing something wrong. Help me please.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList = new ArrayList<Childrens>();
    ChilndrensAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    private static Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;
        final Childrens ls = new Childrens();
        arrayList = ls.getListView();

        adapter = new ChilndrensAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (arrayList.get(position).status == false) {
                    Log.d("True", " True");
                    adapter.setSelecterIndex(position);
                    adapter.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
                    adapter.startUpdateTimer(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (arrayList.get(position).status == true) {
                    Log.d("False", " False");
                    adapter.setSelecterIndex(position);
                    adapter.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
                    adapter.stopUpdateTimer(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class ChilndrensAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList;
    Context context;

    private LayoutInflater cInflater;
    public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<ViewHolder> lstHolders;


    private static final int END = 0;
    private static final int START = 1;
    Timer tmr = new Timer();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.d("Runnable","Runnable");
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                long currentTime = 0L;
                //long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);

                }
            }
        }
    };

    public ChilndrensAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.cInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
        // startUpdateTimer();

    }

    public void startUpdateTimer(final int positon) {

        arrayList.get(positon).status = true;

        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Log.d("tmr","tmr");
                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
                // arrayList.get(positon).time = arrayList.get(positon).time + 1;

            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < lstHolders.size(); i++) {
            //Log.d("Holders: ","H: "+ i+" " + lstHolders.get(i) +" Size: " + lstHolders.size() + " Time: "+arrayList.get(positon).time);
        }
    }

    public void stopUpdateTimer(int position) {

        arrayList.get(position).time = 0;
        arrayList.get(position).status = false;

        // Log.d("Timer Run:", "Time is:" + lstHolders.size());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (arrayList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public void setSelecterIndex(int ind) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggleSelected(Integer position) {
        if (selectedIds.contains(position)) {
            selectedIds.remove(position);

        } else {
            selectedIds.add(position);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (selectedIds.contains(position)) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Childrens getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Childrens item = (Childrens) getItem(position);
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (type) {
                case END:
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_normal, parent, false);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    holder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_control);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
                case START:
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_start, parent, false);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_start);
                    holder.button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
                    holder.holderTimer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerTime);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    synchronized (lstHolders) {

                        lstHolders.add(holder);

                    }
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        switch (type) {
            case END:
                holder.name.setText(item.name);
                holder.info.setText("Time");
                break;
            case START:
                holder.setData(getItem(position));
                holder.name.setText(item.name);

                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getContext());
                        dialog.setTitle("Position " + position);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                        dialog.show();

                    }
                });

                break;
        }


        return convertView;
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView info;
        public TextView holderTimer;
        public ImageView button;

        Childrens mChildrens;


        public void setData(Childrens item) {
            mChildrens = item;
            updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());

        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {


            int sec = (mChildrens.time) % 60;
            int min = (mChildrens.time / 60) % 60;
            holderTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", min) + ":" + String.format("%02d", sec));
            // holderTimer.setText("Time: " + min +":"+ sec);
        }


    }
}
```

**Object:**

```
public class Childrens {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public long answerTime = 0;
    public boolean status;
    public int time;

    final static Childrens CHILDRENS_STATE = new Childrens();

    Childrens(String n, int id, long answerTime) {
        this.name = n;
        this.id = id;
        this.answerTime = answerTime;

    }

    Childrens() {

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;

    }

    public static Childrens getInstance() {
        return CHILDRENS_STATE;
    }

    public ArrayList<Childrens> getListView() {
        ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Childrens c = new Childrens();
            c.status = false;
            c.name = "Child: " + i;
            c.time = 0;
            arrayList.add(c);
            //arrayList.add(new Childrens("Tata"+ i, i, answerTime));
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there was mistake in adapter

```
    public class ChilndrensAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList;
    Context context;

    private LayoutInflater cInflater;
    public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<ViewHolder> lstHolders;


    private static final int END = 0;
    private static final int START =  1;
    Timer tmr = new Timer();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                synchronized (lstHolders) {
                    for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining();

                }
            }
        }
    };

    public ChilndrensAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.cInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();


    }

    public void startUpdateTimer(final int positon) {

        arrayList.get(positon).status = true;

        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
                arrayList.get(positon).time = arrayList.get(positon).time + 1;

            }
        }, 1000, 1000);


    }
    public void stopUpdateTimer(int position) {

        arrayList.get(position).time = 0;
        arrayList.get(position).status = false;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(arrayList == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public void setSelecterIndex(int ind){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void toggleSelected(Integer position){
        if (selectedIds.contains(position)){
            selectedIds.remove(position);

        }else {
            selectedIds.add(position);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (selectedIds.contains(position)){
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public Childrens getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
         Childrens item = (Childrens) getItem(position);
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(convertView == null){
            switch (type){
                case END:
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_normal, parent,false);
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    holder.info = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_control);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
                case START:
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_start, parent, false);
                    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_start);
                    holder.button = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
                    holder.holderTimer = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerTime);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    synchronized (lstHolders) {

                        lstHolders.add(holder);

                    }
                    break;
            }

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        switch (type){
            case END:
                holder.name.setText(item.name);
                holder.info.setText("Time");
                break;
            case START:
                holder.setData(getItem(position));
                holder.name.setText(item.name);

                holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getContext());
                        dialog.setTitle("Position " + position);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                        dialog.show();

                    }
                });

                break;
        }

            return convertView;
        }



    public class ViewHolder{
        private TextView name;
        private TextView info;
        public TextView holderTimer;
        public ImageView button;
        Childrens mChildrens;

        public void setData(Childrens item) {
            mChildrens = item;
            updateTimeRemaining();

        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {

            int sec = (mChildrens.time)%60;
            int min = (mChildrens.time/60)%60;
            holderTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", min) + ":" + String.format("%02d", sec));

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and I want to share with you the ready code.
When creating a new timer I dobovlyaet it to your array of, and with the second click on an element and find this timer is reset to zero it. Although at this point I'm going to send data to the server to zero. Generally it works, check!

```
public class ChilndrensAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList;
Context context;

private LayoutInflater cInflater;
public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<ViewHolder> lstHolders;


private static final int END = 0;
private static final int START =  1;
Timer tmr;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lstHolders) {

            for (ViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                holder.updateTimeRemaining();

            }
        }
    }
};

public ChilndrensAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Childrens> arrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.cInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
    lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();


}

public void startUpdateTimer(final int positon) {

    arrayList.get(positon).status = true;
    tmr = new Timer();
    arrayList.get(positon).timer = tmr;
    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            arrayList.get(positon).time = arrayList.get(positon).time + 1;

        }
    }, 1000, 1000);


}
public void stopUpdateTimer(int position) {
    arrayList.get(position).timer.cancel();
    arrayList.get(position).timer = null;
    arrayList.get(position).time = 0;
    arrayList.get(position).status = false;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(arrayList == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return arrayList.size();
}
public void setSelecterIndex(int ind){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void toggleSelected(Integer position){
    if (selectedIds.contains(position)){
        selectedIds.remove(position);

    }else {
        selectedIds.add(position);

    }
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (selectedIds.contains(position)){
        return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
@Override
public Childrens getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
     Childrens item = (Childrens) getItem(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(convertView == null){
        switch (type){
            case END:
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_normal, parent,false);
                holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.info = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_control);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                break;
            case START:
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = cInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_start, parent, false);
                holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_start);
                holder.button = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
                holder.holderTimer = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerTime);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                synchronized (lstHolders) {
                    lstHolders.add(holder);
                }
                break;
        }

    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    switch (type){
        case END:
            holder.name.setText(item.name);
            holder.info.setText("Time");
            break;
        case START:
            holder.setData(getItem(position));
            holder.name.setText(item.name);
            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getContext());
                    dialog.setTitle("Position " + position);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    dialog.show();

                }
            });

            break;
    }

        return convertView;
    }



public class ViewHolder{
    private TextView name;
    private TextView info;
    public TextView holderTimer;
    public ImageView button;

    Childrens mChildrens;



    public void setData(Childrens item) {
        mChildrens = item;
        updateTimeRemaining();

    }

    public void updateTimeRemaining() {
        int sec = (mChildrens.time)%60;
        int min = (mChildrens.time/60)%60;
        holderTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", min) + ":" + String.format("%02d", sec));

    }


}
```

}